# I cannot upload the file.js to the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I installed the necessary libraries for the button to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbBUt.png)

I got an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9nTv.png)

I added the jquery source file to the page using the drag and drop method.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjAM5.png)

I got an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBTD8.png)

How can I upload the jquery library or javascript library (non-CDN) to my page?
Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first example doesn't work because the path to the file is wrong. The second example doesn't work because you're using a local path (ie. rooted from C:\). Fix the path in the first example and the JS will work fine.

Comment: Thank you. I did not add '/' in the first example. I added it now and it worked.
So, is there an explanation why we cannot run it in the second example? Because in the second example, I dragged and dropped the file and visual studio automatically gave this path.

Comment: You cannot access any files running on the local file system, only those hosted on the web server (even if you're running that web server locally). It's a security restriction.

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan, can you write your comment as an answer to the question? I would like to mark your comment as an answer.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved **in text form**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, is there an explanation why we cannot run it in the second example?

The short answer is, the jquery file is request from the client side and client's browser will firstly download it to the client browser's cache and then use it.

If you directly using the computer path to access the file which means the client has the permission to access all the file inside that path. An attacker could potentially use this to access sensitive files or information on the server, which could lead to data breaches or other malicious activities.

So we suggest you put the file inside the wwwroot folder which is design to  abstract away the actual file system structure.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to understand how and why static file middleware works.

Comment: Rory McCrossan and @Brando Zhang, thank you so much for your comments and responses.
Problem has been solved.
Task can be closed.
Thanks.

Comment: If you feel my answer helped you, you could mark it as answer, it will help other folks who face the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is also correct but
Rory McCrossan's answer answers both examples more accurately. Thank you too.